# Total Price not update When add and remove row

Tags: javascript

Please check this code. When you can add and remove new row then total amount price not updated.

```js
jQuery(document).on("ready", function() {
  initAddRows();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".my-activity").click(function(event) {
    var total = 0;
    $(".my-activity:checked").each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    if (total == 0) {
      $('#amount').val('');
    } else {
      $('#amount').val(total);
    }
  });
});

   $('input[name*="ch-skus"]').click(function() {
    var selValue = $(this).parent().find('input[name*="ch-skus"]:checked').attr('data-attr'); 
    $(this).parent().find('[id^=field]').html('' + selValue + '');
});

function initAddRows() {

  var template = jQuery("#template"),
    dataRows = jQuery("#dataRows")

  jQuery("#btnAdd").on("click", function() {

    var newRow = template.clone(true, true),
      fieldRows = dataRows.find(".fieldRow");

    newRow.attr('id', 'row' + (fieldRows.length + 1)).find('[id]').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).attr("id", jQuery(this).attr("id") + (fieldRows.length + 1));
    });

    newRow.attr('name', 'row' + (fieldRows.length + 1)).find('[name]').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).attr("name", jQuery(this).attr("name") + (fieldRows.length + 1));
    });
    fieldRows.filter(":last").after(newRow);

  });

  dataRows.on("click", ".remove", function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Total </strong>: <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="87" />
 <ol id="dataRows">
   <li class="fieldRow" id="template">
     <select class="items field" name="items" id="items">
       <option value="1" selected="selected">Value</option>
       <option value="1">wq</option>
       <option value="1">ewqe</option>
     </select>
     <input id="xyz" class="my-activity" name="ch-skus" type="radio" data-attr="$45.00" value="45">
     <input id="xyz" class="my-activity" name="ch-skus" type="radio" data-attr="$87.30" value="87" checked="">
     <input id="xyz" class="my-activity" name="ch-skus" type="radio" data-attr="$140.00" value="140">
     <input id="xyz" class="my-activity" name="ch-skus" type="radio" data-attr="$240.00" value="240">
     <input type="text" id="abc" name="abc" />
     <span id="field" class="price-update">$87.30</span>/mo
     <input type="button" class="button remove" id="btnDel" value="Remove Row" />
   </li>
 </ol>
 <div class="buttonHolder">
   <input type="button" class="button add" id="btnAdd" value="Add Row" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in event binding of checkbox click. It only bind event on name matches. You have to select all input which contains that word name.

```
$('input[name*="ch-skus"]').click(function() {
  var selValue = $(this).parent().find('input[name*="ch-skus"]:checked').attr('data-attr');
  $(this).parent().find('[id^=field]').html('' + selValue + '');
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/autcdp9s/

Comment: Can you please tell what behavior you want?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b8eghqLc/

Comment: Ok Sir Price Calculation decimal main bhi ho sakiti hai.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zLw4q5co/

Comment: Two decimal place show in price like 87.30 or 45.00

Comment: Use .toFixed(2) in total.